# Hard-coded mock responses with Mockoon

Tags: mocking, mockoon

I'm trying to mock an API like this,

`GET users/:userID`

Then create hard-coded (not templated or faked) responses using data buckets. My data bucket looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "{{urlParam 'userId'}}": "10000",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "friends": []
  },
  {
    "{{urlParam 'userId'}}": "10001",
    "firstname": "Archie",
    "lastname": "Bunker",
    "friends": []
  }
]
```

Mockoon always returns the entire data bucket contents. Is there any way for me to match the urlParam to an item in my data bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently supported but this feature is being developed.

https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/issues/124

Comment: CRUD routes are available since v1.23.0: https://mockoon.com/old-releases/desktop/#1.23.0

Answer (score 0):

Since v1.23.0 you can use [CRUD endpoints](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/api-endpoints/crud-routes/) which automatically create multiple routes to manipulate JSON in a data bucket:

- GET `/resources`
- GET `/resources/:id`
- POST `/resources`
- PUT `/resources/:id`

And so on.

It also supports filters, search and pagination through the use of query parameters like `?prop_eq=value&page=2`.

Comment: Good to hear. However, I can't make it work. The documentation isn't very clear. I have v.7.0.0.